# how to get the triangle vector coordinate if the triangle area is known

Tags: vector, area

i have a triangle, the vector is A(x1,y1), B(x2,y2), C(x3,y3), these are all known
,then i want to move up the Vector A to a new Position D(x1, y4)--just change the coordinate y, if the new triangle(BCD)'s area is known, how can i caculate the y4?

[image]

thanks to SaiBot, him share a solution like this:
[image]

Comment: my mathematics is poor, this is really a big problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically thinking this can be solved in two steps.

1. move A perpendicular to BC to the upper left until the triangle has the correct size. The size of a triangle is calculated by 1/2 * base * height.
2. move A parallel to BC until A.x = D.x1. This will not change the area of the rectangle.

Comment: i update the question and add a picture, is fit your means? first step A move to A', then A' move to D

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant. You still have to work out the math, but this will make it easier.

Comment: thank you very much, the first step is easy to implement, but the second step how to implement, is any idea?

Comment: You can start from A' + lambda * (B-C) = D. Then splitting this into x and y coordinates, gives you two equations. The first one lets you resolve to lambda. Putting the value for lambda in the second one will give you y4.